# How to run rails app with phusion passenger in production, so the production mongodb also used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, nginx, passenger

I have two (same) rails applications with nginx configs (to use with passenger):

```
> cat ./sites-available/app-production

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app-development.mydomain.com;
  root /path/to/my/production/app/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  rack_env production;
}

> cat ./sites-available/app-development

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app-development.mydomain.com;
  root /path/to/my/development/app/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env development;
}
```

And both have a `./config/mongoid.yml:`

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: app-development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
  options:

production:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: app-production
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
  options:
```

But if I start both of them I see they use the same db: I change some data in `development` and I see the changes in the `production` as well.

Even if I `export RAILS_EVN="production"`, mongodb uses the developmnet db. And if the Phusion Passenger returns some errors it says - it running development mode.

What are the other configurations if these are not enough. Or do I something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

They both have the same server name, so my guess is one will override the other.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app-development.mydomain.com; <-- should be app-production!
  root /path/to/my/production/app/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  rack_env production;
}
```

I also recommend cleaning the Nginx logs then restarting and check the logs for any errors (or increase the log level and retry).  Also it's `RAILS_ENV` not `RAILS_EVN` but `rails_env production;` should take care of that for you.